# Multiple if else conditions in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, if-statement, thymeleaf, ternary

I'm trying to append a css class depending on multiple if cases with the ternary operator.

Is my ternary wrong?

I get the below error:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression error.
```

If I look up the doc or other posts here I couldn't find a correct solution.

My code is the following:

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="product: ${products}">

    <th th:text="${product.status}"
        th:classappend="
           ${product.status == 0} ? class1 :
           ${product.status == 1} ? class2 :
           ${product.status == 2} ? class3 :
           ${product.status == 3} ? class4 : class5">
    </th>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ternary Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) is an operator that operates on **three** operands.

An expression `a ? b : c` evaluates to `b` if the value of `a` is true, and otherwise to `c`.

In your code:

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="product: ${products}">

    <th th:text="${product.status}"
        th:classappend="
           ${product.status == 0} ? class1 :
           ${product.status == 1} ? class2 :
           ${product.status == 2} ? class3 :
           ${product.status == 3} ? class4 : class5">
    </th>
<table>
```

how many operands you have after your first `:`? or to be more precise, what is the expression you have after that colon?

If you have a composite expression, and your `false` candidate value is another ternary operator, you will have to let the engine parse your composite expression, including its nested operators, as:

```
a ? b : c
```

therefore, you have to group your chained nested operators as:

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="product: ${products}">
        <th th:text="${product.status}" th:classappend="
            ${product.status == 0} ? class1 :
            (${product.status == 1} ? class2 :
            (${product.status == 2} ? class3 :
            (${product.status == 3} ? class4 : class5)))">
        </th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

wrapping the other conditions in ()

like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr th:each="product: ${products}">

    <th th:text="${product.status}"
        th:classappend="
           ${product.status == 0} ? class1 :
           (${product.status == 1} ? class2 :
           (${product.status == 2} ? class3 :
           (${product.status == 3} ? class4 : class5")))>
    </th>
<table>
```